# How to create select box in ajax generated update table with values form sql table using pdo

Tags: sql, ajax

I have the following script that i use to update multiple rows from the SQL table ''account''.

In the table ''account'' I have column named category, the `cat_ID` form table ''categories'' is inserted as value in the table ''accounts'' in the column category.

I now have those values hard coded and i want them to be selectable as dropdown list from the table categories, cat_ID as value and cat_name as name of the category. I have tried a lot, googled a lot, but i cant get this to work.

All i want is to have the options fetched from the SQL table categories and use them as dropdown select option in the update option of the script, which are now hard coded now and is working fine.

The hard coded part:

```
  html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="category[]" id="category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox"><option value="4">Moet gerankt worden</option><option value="6">Wordt gerankt</option><option value="5">Current BF Holder</option><option value="7">Main Account</option><option value="8">Money Private</option><option value="11">CB/Suc</option><option value="13">Casino Holder</option><option value="15">Wordt Gestockt</option><option value="10">Dont use, ask first!</option><option value="14">Stockgeld</option><option value="0"></option></select></td>';
```

The SQL select call:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, c.cat_color, c.cat_name, c.cat_txt FROM account a LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.cat_ID = a.category WHERE `betaald` = 'Yes' AND `secret` = 'No'";
 
 
 
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

if($statement->execute())
{
 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  $data[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The whole script.

```
 <script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    
 $(document).on('click', '.loginBtn', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');  
      var tds = row.find('td');    
      var name = ''
      var cnt = 0;
      $.each(tds, function() {   
          if(cnt == 1) {
              name = $(this).text();
              return false;
          }
          cnt++;
      });
      $.ajax({
          url:"select_login_update.php",
          method:"POST",
          data: {name: name},
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success:function(data)
          {
            if(data !== '') {
              var email = data[0].email;
              var pword = data[0].password
              var frm = document.createElement('form');
              frm.setAttribute('action', 'http://login.php');
              frm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
              frm.setAttribute('target', 'view');
              var frmEmail = document.createElement('input');
              frmEmail.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              frmEmail.setAttribute('name', 'email');
              frmEmail.setAttribute('value', email);
              var frmPass = document.createElement('input');
              frmPass.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              frmPass.setAttribute('name', 'password');
              frmPass.setAttribute('value', pword);
              frm.appendChild(frmEmail)
              frm.appendChild(frmPass)
              document.body.appendChild(frm);
              window.open('', 'view');
              frm.submit();
            } else {
              console.log('empty data');
            }
          },
          error:function(xhr, status, err)
          {
            console.log('select_login_update.php error ' + err);
          }
      });
  });
  
   function fetch_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"select_update_all.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                var html = '';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                {var purpose = data[count].purpose;
    if(purpose == "BFH") purpose = "Holders";
    else if(purpose == "CAS") purpose = "Ranking";
    else if(purpose == "PWA") purpose = "Money Rankers";
    else if(purpose == "Crew") purpose = "PW Accounts";
    else if(purpose == "Crew2") purpose = "The Colombo Family";
    else if(purpose == "Crew3") purpose = "Hassinions";
    else if(purpose == "aa") purpose = "Admin Account";
    else if(purpose == "slist") purpose = "Stocklist";
    else if(purpose == "Eragon") purpose = "Eragon";
    else if(purpose == "NP") purpose = "Non Paying";
    else if(purpose == "DA") purpose = "Deadly Alliance";
                
                    html += '<tr >';
                    html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="checkbox"  id="'+data[count].id+'" data-name="'+data[count].name+'" data-bullets="'+data[count].bullets+'" data-rang="'+data[count].rang+'" data-category="'+data[count].category+'"  data-door="'+data[count].door+'" data-ranker="'+data[count].ranker+'" data-purpose="'+data[count].purpose+'" data-notes="'+data[count].notes+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].bullets+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].rang+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].ranker+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].cat_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+purpose+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].notes+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].door+'</td>';
                    html += '<td class=\"footer\"><button type="button" class="loginBtn" >Login</button></td></tr>';
                }
                $('tbody').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();

    $(document).on('change', '.check_box', function(){
        var html = '';
        if(this.checked)
        {
            html = '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-bullets="'+$(this).data('bullets')+'" data-rang="'+$(this).data('rang')+'" data-category="'+$(this).data('category')+'" data-door="'+$(this).data('door')+'" data-ranker="'+$(this).data('ranker')+'" data-purpose="'+$(this).data('purpose')+'" data-notes="'+$(this).data('notes')+'" class="check_box" checked /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="text" name="name[]" class="editbox" value="'+$(this).data("name")+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="number" onClick="this.select()" style="width:58px !important;" name="bullets[]" class="editbox" value="'+$(this).data("bullets")+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="rang[]" id="rang_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox"><option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option><option value="Low Life">Low Life</option><option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option><option value="Hitman">Hitman</option><option value="Assassin">Assassin</option><option value="Local Boss">Local Boss</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Godfather">Godfather</option></select></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input  type="text" name="ranker[]" class="editbox" value="'+$(this).data("ranker")+'" /></td>';
           html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="category[]" id="category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox"><option value="4">Moet gerankt worden</option><option value="6">Wordt gerankt</option><option value="5">Current BF Holder</option><option value="7">Main Account</option><option value="8">Money Private</option><option value="11">CB/Suc</option><option value="13">Casino Holder</option><option value="15">Wordt Gestockt</option><option value="10">Dont use, ask first!</option><option value="14">Stockgeld</option><option value="0"></option></select></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="purpose[]" id="purpose_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox"><option value="">-- No Type --</option><option value="Killer">Killers</option><option value="BFH">Holders</option><option value="CAS">Ranking</option><option value="PWA">Money Rankers</option><option value="Crew">PW Accounts</option><option value="Crew2">The Colombo Family</option><option value="Deadly Alliance">Deadly Alliance</option><option value="Crew3">Hassinions</option><option value="aa">Admin Account</option><option value="NP">Non Paying</option><option value="Eragon">Eragon</option><option value="slist">Stocklist</option></select></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="text" name="notes[]" class="editbox" value="'+$(this).data("notes")+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input disabled="" style="width:50px !important;" name="door[]" class="editbox" value="'+$(this).data("door")+'" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="submit" name="multipleupdatedata2allacc" id="multipleupdatedata2allacc" class="submit" value="Update" /></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            html = '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-bullets="'+$(this).data('bullets')+'" data-rang="'+$(this).data('rang')+'" data-category="'+$(this).data('category')+'" data-door="'+$(this).data('door')+'" data-ranker="'+$(this).data('ranker')+'" data-purpose="'+$(this).data('purpose')+'" data-notes="'+$(this).data('notes')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('name')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('bullets')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('rang')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('ranker')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('category')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('purpose')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('notes')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('door')+'</td>'; 
            html += '<td class=\"footer\"><button type="button" class="loginBtn">Login</button></td></tr>';
                       
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
        $('#rang_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('rang'));
        $('#category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('category'));
        $('#purpose_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('purpose'));
     
    });

    $('#update_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"update_multiple.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function()
                {
                    alert('Data Updated');
                    fetch_data();
                }
            })
        }
    });

});  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried running that query from the command line or whatever tool that you might have? ... The `ORDER BY` clause looks suspicious to me, and you likely have a syntax error.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your reaction. The order by clausule works fine in production. Besides that i dont see how that is relevant to my question. For the clearity of the sql statement i have edited my question and removed this clausule. As it is not relevant to the goal i am trying to reach, which is creating a drowdown option box based on the selected values from the table categories.

Comment: I understand the part about creating the drop-down values from SQL, so if there may have been an error could have been relevant. Anyway, other than that, are there any browser console errors for the javascript when run? Also, what database version is in use?

Comment: Ok makes sence when you put it like that. There are no console logs the database is mariadb sql database. The code is running on php 7.4. I just cant find a good example or explanation how to do a dropdown in a script like this while getting input from the database.

Comment: So you want to build the category select in the ajax that uses `select_update_all`, correct? (instead of in the checkbox change area?)

Comment: Hello Paul, no than i must have been unclear. I need those hardcoded options in the select tag with id category and name category to be selected from the sql database as options. So that the dropdown list gets its options from the table categories instead of writing the options manualy as i did now. Than the user can select one of these options and update the account table. The cat_ID needs to be inserted in the account table.

Comment: The part about getting categories from the DB, to build the select options, is clear. Where the intent to retrieve and use the list is not. At the moment, the category list is hard coded in the checkbox change handling, but near the end of the question has `in the update option of the script` which made me think about the select_update_all area in my last comment.

Comment: The hardcoded values are used to update the account table. The goals is to get these hard coded values from the database to update that value in the database. This sheet excists to update rows of data, the user can vink as many rows as they wish and than the rows become editable with input and select options to update tue excisting data. Where categories is one of after its done it displays the updated rows.

Comment: So to be clear. User opens page, sees all presented rows, selects the rows he wants to edit, user changes what needs changing. As the category which is now hardcoded and needs to be a auto filled drop list with the options stored in the categories table. The last part of the script is used for when a wrong row is selected to get back to the original stored values. When done it updates all selected rows to account table. I hope i have explained it well

Comment: By the way, thank you so far allready! You are the only one reacting.. so either what i am asking is very dificult or i am not clear in my question, or it is suposed to be that easy that no one cares to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is somewhat easy, and believe it or not, even easier for what you need. So, based on what you have, you really only need a string of `<option>` tags for the `<select>`, which only needs to be fetched once for reference. The tougher part is usually making the new handling work with code that already exists, if possible, without having to refactor.

Try the things below, I've added another ajax to pre-fetch the category options after the document is ready: (see the two `// New` comment markers)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var categoryOptions = ''; // New var

  $.ajax({  // New ajax
    url: 'get_categories.php',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function(data)
    {
      categoryOptions = data;
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, err)
    {
      console.log('get_categories.php error ' + err);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.loginBtn', function(e) {
```

Content of get_categories.php: (replace with your DB handling)

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

// Get the category id/name pairs
$result = $db->query("SELECT cat_ID, cat_name FROM categories");

$options = '';

// Build the options
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $options .= '<option value="' . $row['cat_ID'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
}

// The option 0 was last, keeping the same way.
$options .= '<option value="0"></option>';

echo $options;
```

Then change the categories html from:

```
html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="category[]" id="category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox"><option value="4">Moet gerankt worden</option><option value="6">Wordt gerankt</option><option value="5">Current BF Holder</option><option value="7">Main Account</option><option value="8">Money Private</option><option value="11">CB/Suc</option><option value="13">Casino Holder</option><option value="15">Wordt Gestockt</option><option value="10">Dont use, ask first!</option><option value="14">Stockgeld</option><option value="0"></option></select></td>';
```

...to:

```
html += '<td class=\"footer\"><select name="category[]" id="category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="editbox">' + categoryOptions + '</select></td>';
```

I believe that should achieve the desired goal.

Comment: That is exactly what i was searching for ! many thanks !